# Setting project for eclipse using maven

Tags: eclipse, maven-2

I'm trying to start modifying an existing application with Eclipse. Actually I had it working before, but I deleted the project, and now with "mvn eclipse:eclipse" I get the following:

```
[INFO] Resource directory's path matches an existing source directory. Resources will be merged with the source directory src/main/resources
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Request to merge when 'filtering' is not identical. Original=resource src/main/resources: output=target/classes, include=[atlassian-plugin.xml], exclude=[**/*.java], test=false, filtering=true,
 merging with=resource src/main/resources: output=target/classes, include=[], exclude=[atlassian-plugin.xml|**/*.java], test=false, filtering=false
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Trace
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Request to merge when 'filtering' is not identical. Original=resource src/main/resources: output=target/classes, include=[atlassian-plugin.xml],
 exclude=[**/*.java], test=false, filtering=true, merging with=resource src/main/resources: output=target/classes, include=[], exclude=[atlassian-plugin.xml|**/*.java], test=false, filtering=false
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:583)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeStandaloneGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:512)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:482)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:330)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:291)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:142)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:336)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:129)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:287)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Request to merge when 'filtering' is not identical. Original=resource src/main/resources: output=target/classes, include=[atlassian-plugin.xm
l], exclude=[**/*.java], test=false, filtering=true, merging with=resource src/main/resources: output=target/classes, include=[], exclude=[atlassian-plugin.xml|**/*.java], test=false, filtering=false
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.eclipse.EclipseSourceDir.merge(EclipseSourceDir.java:302)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.eclipse.EclipsePlugin.extractResourceDirs(EclipsePlugin.java:1605)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.eclipse.EclipsePlugin.buildDirectoryList(EclipsePlugin.java:1490)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.eclipse.EclipsePlugin.createEclipseWriterConfig(EclipsePlugin.java:1180)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.eclipse.EclipsePlugin.writeConfiguration(EclipsePlugin.java:1043)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.ide.AbstractIdeSupportMojo.execute(AbstractIdeSupportMojo.java:511)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:451)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:558)
        ... 16 more
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Would this make it better?

```
 mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-eclipse-plugin:2.6:eclipse
```

> This tells maven to use version 2.6 (which still works) instead of the default 2.7 (which doesn't).
>   You'll have to issue the command like this every time, so it's a little inconvenient whereas the file changes above should result in a one-time fix, but this way you don't risk accidentally breaking something else and you don't have to go looking for files.
>   If you can't remember the command syntax, copy it into a text file for easier reference.

See [this thread](http://forums.atlassian.com/thread.jspa?threadID=34952&tstart=1).

It does mention a recent change in the Maven Eclipse Plugin:

- [MECLIPSE-551 regression - Resources are excluded if resource dir equals source dir](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc?view=rev&revision=779829)
- [MECLIPSE-551 Jira ticket](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MECLIPSE-551)

Comment: if someone is still struggling with this see this https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=317900

Answer (score 8):

I think VonC's answer is the right one (+1) if you are using the eclipse:eclipse goal. Personally I find it more trouble than it's worth and instead use m2eclipse to manage the dependencies, committing the eclipse metadata files to SCM.

To avoid having to invoke eclipse:eclipse with the fully-qualified name as VonC suggests, you can configure the plugin in your pom to use the exact version. This is [good practice](http://www.sonatype.com/people/2008/04/maven-209-released/#more-607) anyway.

In the pom, specify the plugin as follows:

```
<build>
...
  <plugins>
  ...
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.6</version>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Then whenever you invoke the eclipse plugin, version 2.6 will be used.

Comment: m2eclipse and specifying the version: +1

Comment: please note though that by relying on m2eclipse to handle configuration, you'll become dependent of a (working!) Eclipse installation in order to build your product. Maven as such works on the commandline. For a hobbyist project, or a short lived small sized project, this might be irrelevant, but within an industrial set-up it's typically unacceptable, to have the build process depend on some developers PC

Comment: @Icythyo that is nonsense. All using m2eclipse means is that your existing Maven dependencies are managed automatically within Eclipse. It in no way forces you to use Eclipse as the pom.xml still describes the entire build.

Answer (score 0):

Can we have a look to the pom.xml of the project?

Did you try to run the `mvn clean eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse` command?

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't help (I hadn't tried that, though, thanks). mvn package btw. works...