# Maven: correct way to enable filtering on a subset of resources

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, m2eclipse

Consider this directory structure:

```
src/main/resources/
    resource1.properties
    subdir/
        resource2.properties
```

I need `resource2.properties` (and its siblings) to undergo [Maven filtering](http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-filtering/) but would rather exclude all other resources from filtering.

This is a safety: other property files may contain `${xxx}` tokens which should not get substituted.  I do need to preserve the source directory structure on the `target`.

In the end, I found that the only way to achieve this (in a way that doesn't break maven-eclipse-plugin's `eclipse:eclipse`) seems to be:

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>subdir/**</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </resource>
    <resource>
        <!-- 'subdir' resources need placeholder substitution (ie: "filtering") -->
        <directory>src/main/resources/subdir</directory>
        <targetPath>${project.build.outputDirectory}/subdir</targetPath>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

You could say this is convoluted and potentially brittle.  This is using Maven 2.2.1 with maven-eclipse-plugin v2.8 (latest).

Other, slightly less convoluted versions of the above have triggered issues with maven-eclipse-plugin, which complains with smth similar to:

`[INFO] Request to merge when 'filtering' is not identical. Original=resource src/main/resources: output=target/classes, include=[], exclude=[subdir/**|**/*.java], test=false, filtering=false, merging with=resource src/main/resources: output=target/classes, include=[subdir/**], exclude=[**/*.java], test=false, filtering=true`

This recalls [this old thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397903/setting-project-for-eclipse-using-maven): the workaround mentioned there works (downgrading to v2.6 of maven-eclipse-plugin) but this should no longer be required because the related bugs are marked as fixed?

This doesn't look like too far fetched a use case, yet I'm struggling...

Comment: I would suggest to use m2eclipse instead of maven-eclipse-plugin...

Comment: Agree, though it's certainly not without its own quirks ;-)  The issue here is that some team members insit on using command-line tools...

Comment: Command line is very good. I prefer the command line as well, but if i work with eclipse i use m2eclipse cause it makes working simpler.

Answer (score 2):

What about this:

```
   <build>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>false</filtering>
      </resource>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources/subdir</directory>
        <targetPath>${project.build.OutputDirectory}/subdir</targetPath>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <includes>
          <include>**/*</include>
        </includes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
   </build>
```

Comment: Thanks for this @khmarbaise. Looks very similar to my solution above. Actually, both share an issue: it looks like maven-eclipse-plugin also cannot deal with `<targetPath>${project.build.OutputDirectory}/subdir</targetPath>`. As soon as you add this in, you get: `[INFO] Cant canonicalize system path: {0} Embedded error: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect`